# Return only newest record in database with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I return only one (the newest) record in database using SQL?

As example I have records:

```
dateFrom     dateTo   dateInserted
2017-08-09  2017-08-20 2017-08-10
2017-08-15  2017-08-17 2017-08-15
```

And my query is to return record that has `dateFrom` and `dateTo` between or even `2017-08-09 and 2017-08-20`. So now both records will be returned, but is it possible to return only one record, the newest one, that means `2017-08-15  2017-08-17 2017-08-15` in this case?

I know how to sort by date, but then, anyway, both records will be returned only sorted, as example:

```
Select dateFrom,dateTo
From  temp t1
where date = (select max(date) from temp where t1.name =temp.name)
order by date desc
```

I need only one record cause asterisk can't work with two results or so...

Comment: use `limit 1` with the `order by ` clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `LIMIT 1`

```
SELECT dateFrom, dateTo
FROM  temp t1
WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM temp WHERE t1.name = temp.name)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: wow, that was simple... How did I miss that... Thank you very much!